# MacOS launch Jupyter notebook raising ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlite2'

Tags: python-3.x, macos, jupyter-notebook

My computer system is **MacOS Sonoma 14.1.1**. When I start jupyter notebook from the command or Anaconda, the following error appears. How to solve it? Thanks.

```
/Users/mac/anaconda3/bin/jupyter_mac.command ; exit;

The default interactive shell is now zsh.
To update your account to use zsh, please run `chsh -s /bin/zsh`.
For more details, please visit https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208050.
(base) MacBook-Pro-2:~ mac$ /Users/mac/anaconda3/bin/jupyter_mac.command ; exit;
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mac/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 9, in <module>
    import sqlite3
  File "/Users/mac/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 57, in <module>
    from sqlite3.dbapi2 import *
  File "/Users/mac/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/mac/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-311-darwin.so, 0x0002): Symbol not found: _sqlite3_enable_load_extension
  Referenced from: <55C163F0-89FA-3BFF-8FCB-DFF6F31B1972> /Users/mac/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-311-darwin.so
  Expected in:     <567CDD63-191D-36E4-959B-7DE47C7AFD7A> /usr/lib/libsqlite3.dylib

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mac/anaconda3/bin/jupyter-notebook", line 7, in <module>
    from notebook.notebookapp import main
  File "/Users/mac/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/notebook/notebookapp.py", line 83, in <module>
    from .services.sessions.sessionmanager import SessionManager
  File "/Users/mac/anaconda3/lib/python3.11/site-packages/notebook/services/sessions/sessionmanager.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlite2'
logout

Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.
```

Comment: looks like this problem. https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/issues/1594.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like this problem. github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/issues/1594

see https://github.com/jupyterhub/jupyterhub/issues/1594#issuecomment-354775138

what is
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH set to?

"DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH should approximately never be set, and if set, only to non-default paths, such as ~/work/mystuff/lib, and only for temporary working environments (e.g. never in ~/.bashrc). The cause is that you have told the system that any library found in /usr/lib should be loaded (in this case sqlite) in preference to other locations, e.g. ...conda/lib/, which is where the sqlite that Python requires is located."